# ¿Cómo puedo alinear imagenes e iconos en un td?

Tags: html5, email, tablas

estoy ocupando Cerberus Master para hacer un mailing, pero no puedo alinear el logo y los iconos de redes sociales, porque la tabla está forzando el contenido al centro, y al momento de poner otro td se hacen dos columnas, dejando vacía una y la otra amontonando el contenido.
¿Cómo puedo hacer que una se alinea a la derecha y otra a la izquierda utilizando la misma fila?

Este es mi código:

```
 <table align="center" role="presentation" cellspacing="0" cellpadding="0" width="600" style="margin: 0 auto;" class="email-container">
        <tr>
            <td style="padding: 20px;">
                    <img src="Logo.png" width="150" height="60" alt="alt_text" style="height: auto; font-family: sans-serif; font-size: 15px; line-height: 5px;">
                <a href="url.web.com" style="text-decoration:none;">
                    <img src="imgende.com" height="30" alt="web.png">
                </a>
                <a href="fbcorporativo" style="text-decoration:none; padding: 10px 40px;">
                    <img src="imagende.com">
                </a>
                <a href="Linkedincorporativo" style="text-decoration:none;">
                    <img src="imagende.com" height="30" alt="linkedin.png">
                </a>
            </td>
        </tr>
```

[image: logos]

Comment: ¿puedes poner una imagen de como te estan quedando alineadas las imagenes?

Comment: agrega el tamaño de las imágenes y te recomiendo encerrarlas en divs

Comment: @JohnySalazar listo, la imagen de arriba es como se ve la tabla, no puedo separarlos en la misma fila pero uno que quede a la izquierda y otro a la derecha

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Tienes dos opciones:

- Encerrar cada una de las imagenes en su propio `<td>` (ajusta el padding de cada td):

  ```
  <tr>
      <td style="padding: 20px;">
              <img src="Logo.png" width="150" height="60" alt="alt_text" style="height: auto; font-family: sans-serif; font-size: 15px; line-height: 5px;">
      </td>
      <td style="padding: 20px;">
          <a href="url.web.com" style="text-decoration:none;">

              <img src="imgende.com" height="30" alt="web.png">
          </a>
      </td>
      <td style="padding: 20px;">
          <a href="fbcorporativo" style="text-decoration:none; padding: 10px 40px;">
              <img src="imagende.com">
          </a>
      </td>
      <td style="padding: 20px;">
          <a href="Linkedincorporativo" style="text-decoration:none;">
              <img src="imagende.com" height="30" alt="linkedin.png">
          </a>
      </td>
  </tr>
  ```

  - O encerrar cada imagen en un `<div class="imagen">` y estilizarlas con CSS

Comment: Lo intentaré con esas opciones, si funciona marco la respuesta correcta, gracias.

Comment: La manera "correcta" de implementar algo asi es usando CSS-queries o Flexbox. Pero ya depende de la compatibilidad que quieras (puedas) ofrecer ya que no todos los navegadores antiguos lo permiten. Tambien tienes librerias que implementen "grid layout" como Bootstrap o Materialize que puedes usar para conseguir efectos como el que buscas. Pero ya seria algo general para todo tu proyect.

Comment: Utilicé Bootstrap para mailing, pero me dio problemas con los estilos ya en producción, por eso me bajé el Cerberus, no había pensando en flexbox, voy a probarlo a ver que tal reacciona.